# How Are Transistors Used to Represent Logic Gates

Tags: transistors, logic-gates

How are transistors arranged to form Logic Gates.

Use an AND gate as an example

Comment: We are not here to give you homework answers on a silver platter.  Clearly you haven't even done the very basic obvious research.

Comment: Homework questions with no attempt at an answer are off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an AND gate that uses three transistors:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLUrmF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: That's... pretty horrifying. +1